# Grafana 8.1.1 - Postgresql Exception :- long series must be sorted ascending by time to be converted

Tags: postgresql, grafana, influxdb, timescaledb, grafana-variable

I am trying to fetch metrics from postgresql (timeseries) database in Grafana (Ver 8)  using below query .

Just wondering its throwing below exception :-

**failed to convert long to wide series when converting from dataframe: long series must be sorted ascending by time to be converted**

```
SELECT time, cpu_count,CASE WHEN step = 0 THEN 'Today' ELSE (-interval)::text END AS metric
FROM
-- sub-query to generate the intervals
( SELECT step, (step||'day')::interval AS interval FROM generate_series(0,3) g(step) order by interval asc) g_offsets 
JOIN LATERAL (
SELECT
-- adding set interval to time values
  time_bucket('15m',time + interval )::timestamptz AS time, avg(limit_cpu) AS cpu_count FROM cpu_model 

WHERE
  time BETWEEN $__timeFrom()::timestamptz - interval AND $__timeTo()::timestamptz - interval 
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1,2 ASC
) l ON true
```

Would appreciate it if some one can help me to find the error or provide solution .

Comment: Hello Pravek what version of Grafana are you using? Searching for that error came up with a Grafana bug that had a long discussion. That was with Grafana version 8.0.3.. Have a quick google and check if it fits? I think there were bug reports for this.

Comment: Thanks  greenweeds ! I am using v8.1.1 . Could you please advise if query can be modified a bit to get desired result. I am trying to get the metrics of current and previous days.

Comment: it's a wild guess, but maybe try putting `ORDER BY 1 ASC` at the end of your query? (so NOT inside a subquery) @Pravek

Comment: Can't exactly tell by the query that's in the OP, but if you are trying to fetch time series metrics, and you've selected the 'Format As: Timeseries' option, then your results must be in ascending order by time. Try using a table visualization and the "Format As: Table" option to see what the order of the data is.

Comment: @KevinMinehart that did the trick for me! Nice one!

Answer (score 2):

In my case, for some reason sorting the data by time ASC solved the issue. Grafana 's error was correct.

```
SELECT
  time AS "time",
  pair,
  price as value
FROM currency_pair_price
WHERE
  time/1000 >= 1662481845 AND time/1000 <= 1662568245
  AND pair = 'BTCBUSD'
ORDER BY time ASC;
```